# Using Alasql can you replace null column with empty string

Tags: angularjs, excel, alasql

In my angular controller i have ExportToExcel function, which is using alasql to export data to Excel and the data is coming from angular array. 
**The issue is the array might contains null as data, is it a way to replace null to empty string in alasql**

Following is the function

```
 ac.ExportToExcel = function () {
        var time = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);
        alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("ExchangeReport' + time + '.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ? WHERE BillingPeriod = "' + ac.ExchangeReport.BillingPeriod + '" or "' + ac.ExchangeReport.BillingPeriod + '" = "" ', [ac.ExchangeDatas]);
    }
```

And this is my data source

```
ac.ExchangeDatas = [];
```

from

```
        ac.GetAllExchangeData = function () {
        AccountRepository.GetAllExchangeData().$promise.then(
            function (data) {
                ac.ExchangeDatas = data.result;
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log("error in GetAllExchangeData : " + err);
            }
        );
    }
```

Data in excel:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
var old = JSON.stringify($scope.achData).replace(/null/g, '""'); //convert to 
JSON string and puts empty string in place of null values   
var newArray = JSON.parse(old); //convert back to array  
alasql('select * into XLSX("amar.xlsx", {headers:true}) from ?', [newArray]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `COALESCE`, though you need to list all the columns like `COALESCE(YourColumn,'') AS YourColumn` instead of `*`. See https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Coalesce